# Performance Issues (DOM GC / Major GC) [help]

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I've been strugling with some performance issue related to a scroll navigation and I can't figure out how to make it smooth.

The website I'm talking about can be seen [here](https://mako.900k.fr/)
the script annimating the sections can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/leovdw/39ca564b1843f6413a7c800aca7dcb0a) (Lines 96 to 120)

The script is applying to all the section a translateY of the current section number (refered by count in my code) but I need to triger other annimations when we get to the creation part, I have to know when we enter the section, when we leave and which creation is seen, That's why there is a lot of Ifs with count and oldcount, but when we enter for the first time the creation section there is a long interruption in the annimation which is (I think) caused by a "Major GC", 
I tried to investigate what happend at that time (screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq9Ef.jpg)) now, what I woud like to find is what code is causing the annimation to stop, what is trigering this DOM GC, basicly how to make my code smooth.

Thanks evryone for your time reading my post, sorry for my bad english and have a great day

Comment: please add the relevant code parts directly to the question.

Comment: You might want to add throttling to the mousewheel event

Comment: Relevent part is line 96 to 120 of the script I linked, coud you give futher exeplaination of what you mean with  "add throttling to the mousewheel event"

Comment: the "mousescroll" event triggers every few milliseconds, that is usually much faster than needed. Just ignore every second event and you effectively double performance without loosing functionality

Comment: @JonasWilms I have that fetaure developed, kindof, in my script at the end of my function I add (and delete) an event listener to see when a section's transition ends, and then change a velue of a variable to true, if you scroll and the previous annimation isn't finished nothing is executed (That's line 41 of my script

`if (is_finished == 1) {`

So even if the event trigers more it shoudn't impact performance, right ?